# Location context not working in NGINX config file

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config, nginx-location

I am new to nginx and writing the config files I am editing the default file present at location /etc/nginx/sites-available/default, I am using Ubuntu OS.

I am facing issue to access the kibana web UI hosted at http://localhost:5601 on server

on my web browser I am doing http://server-name/ and I am able to access the index file similarly if I change location from /app/home/ to / I am able to access the kibana web UI.

But when I use location as /app/home/ either of the service is not working I am not able to access index.html and neither http://localhost:5601.

Please let me know what mistake I am doing.

I can see in the nginx access.log file the request are reaching

`10.32.2.13 - - [24/Nov/2020:09:58:27 +0000] "GET /app/kibana/ HTTP/1.1" 200 20917 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.67 Safari/537.36"`

`10.32.2.13 - - [24/Nov/2020:09:58:28 +0000] "GET /bundles/app/core/bootstrap.js HTTP/1.1" 404 209 "http://server-name/app/kibana/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.67 Safari/537.36`

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name  <server-name>;
    root /usr/share/nginx/elk_website;

    location /app/home/ {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5601;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

    location /{
        index   index.html;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason your kibana Web UI doesn't working is quite obvious - the assets URIs requested by kibana (`/bundles/app/core/bootstrap.js` on the second line of the log you supplied) does not fall under the `location /app/home/ { ... }` and are trying to be served via your root location (`location / { ... }`). To made kibana add your URI prefix to its assets URIs you should change the [`server.basePath`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/settings.html#server-basePath) value in your `kibana.yml` file.